# How do I modify Bootstrap CSS files when I'm using the Bootstrap package?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor

Bootstrap **is** loaded into my project, judging by the following that appear in my .html file after running the `meteor add bootstrap` command.

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/packages/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css?e5976308949024b827360231c67b6f50ee1cf8c5">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/packages/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css?b66c9c5bfb9556bf343298e3fe6e49c39db8c222">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/packages/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-override.css?15fa5b55da5c16ed92ffe0c85c0d6aa0867b9c7f">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/music.css?2b2e8ef7fc8414f9b064e2d1faf7be37f8e97a97">
```

However, there was no bootstrap directory under packages, and I couldn't find any reference to Bootstrap in my project directory (apart from the files that built?), as shown by the following results of the `find` command for all css files in the dir.

```
music-meteor-master/music.css
music-meteor-master/.meteor/local/build/programs/client/packages/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css
music-meteor-master/.meteor/local/build/programs/client/packages/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-override.css
music-meteor-master/.meteor/local/build/programs/client/packages/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css
music-meteor-master/.meteor/local/build/programs/client/app/music.css
```

Am I doing this incorrectly? How do I work with Bootstrap on Meteor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make CSS changes, you'll need access to the original LESS files that get interpreted on the fly into that CSS. The meteor package that includes the original LESS is at:

https://github.com/ianserlin/meteor-bootstrap-less

Ref: [What is LESS](http://lesscss.org/)?